# How to run JS code only on desktop without user agent sniffing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS, and I want to disable a feature on every device but desktops (because it's a performance hog). It's only an animation, and it makes mobiles lag for its duration (my Note 4 is quite fast and it still lags a bit).

So, I only want to run this animation, when on desktop. Something like this:

```
if (IsDeviceADesktop() )
     playAnimation();
```

**I know of all the answers invlovling User agent sniffing, and I want to avoid that if possible.** (it's completely unreliable).

Comment: So the `window.navigator` is out of the question then?

Comment: Maybe instead of detecting desktop, you could detect the lag and stop the animation

Comment: Perhaps you could give the browser a quick benchmark of some kind instead and decide whether it's capable of handling the animation? More powerful or more optimised mobiles may well be able to handle it [in the future]. Same problem as with user agent sniffing really: don't categorically rule out a whole class of devices because of assumptions.

Comment: Can you please say what kind of animation is it? What comes to my mind is conditioning it upon either dimensions of the screen or intervals between the animation (if time between frames is too big, disable the animation)

Comment: @deceze That's correct, maybe future mobiles, or lighter animations will run, but is it wise to run a benchmark on a mobile? Wouldn't it waste its battery etc?

Comment: Maybe only proof if window size is big enough?

Comment: @eithedog It's an animation of a chart, using the ZingChart library. Edit: actually it's 8 charts :P

Comment: Not necessarily a full benchmark, just something that gives you some number. Maybe a 1 second long background web worker or something which just increases a counter. Or detect the availability of certain hardware acceleration or something. Simple a more concrete criterion than "is mobile"...

Comment: wouldn't just checking how long it took to render all the other elements on the page work?

Comment: I believe the proper answer is exactly what @ArturoTorresSánchez suggested. Dynamically altering the load based on things such as fps, or the duration of an execution, is better than just detecting if it is a certain type. If a system can't handle the load, regardless of the type, reduce the load.

Comment: It does sound like the proper solution.